# Modify content of DataTemplate in code for a Grid control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, grid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have the following Xaml for a grid and I want to be able to modify the value of the Content in code. I want to depending on the condition, not display the "[+]". How do I do that. Also how do i trigger an event to make the change. I am using an Infragistic XamGrid but I think it will apply to other grids too.

```
<ig:UnboundColumn Key="Sel" x:Name="ubcSel" IsFixed="Left" Width="44" HeaderText="   " PropertyChanged="UnboundColumn_PropertyChanged">
                                <ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <HyperlinkButton Name="hblSel" Click="hblSel_Click"
                                             Content="[+]" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate>
                            </ig:UnboundColumn>
```

Comment: here is the part of the xamal:

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use binding on the content property and place the conditional logic in an exposed ViewModel property?